# AVAssetWriter is recording empty, 0kb, .mp4 files from a custom video stream on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetwriterinput

I am seeing a video stream and making `.mp4` files so I am doing most of this correctly. My problem is that my video files are 0kb, empty. I'm using an iOS device to control a separate device with a camera. This camera is sending a video stream to the iOS device and that stream is decoded into a `CMSampleBuffer` then turned into a `CVPixelBuffer` and displayed in an `UIImageView`. I'm displaying the video just fine(and a separate issue is that I'm getting -12909 errors if you know anything about fixing that pls leave a comment).

I tried recording the `CMSampleBuffer` objects but I was told by the compiler errors that I needed to exclude output settings. So I removed those and it saves empty files now.

When the stream starts I call this:

```
func beginRecording() {
    handlePhotoLibraryAuth()
    createFilePath()
    guard let videoOutputURL = outputURL,
        let vidWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: videoOutputURL, fileType: AVFileType.mov) else {
            fatalError("AVAssetWriter error")
    }
    let vidInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: nil)

    guard vidWriter.canAdd(vidInput) else {
        print("Error: Cant add video writer input")
        return
    }
    vidInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    vidWriter.add(vidInput)
    guard vidWriter.startWriting() else {
        print("Error: Cant write with vid writer")
        return
    }
    vidWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime.zero)

    self.videoWriter = vidWriter
    self.videoWriterInput = vidInput
    self.isRecording = true
    print("Recording: \(self.isRecording)")
}
```

And this ends it:

```
func endRecording() {
    guard let vidInput = videoWriterInput, let vidWriter = videoWriter else {
        print("Error, no video writer or video input")
        return
    }
    vidInput.markAsFinished()
    vidWriter.finishWriting {
        print("Finished Recording")
        self.isRecording = false
        guard vidWriter.status == .completed else {
            print("Warning: The Video Writer status is not completed, status: \(vidWriter.status)")
            return
        }
        print("VideoWriter status is completed")
        self.saveRecordingToPhotoLibrary()
    }
}
```

I determined my append operation on `AVAssetWriterInput` is failing

Here is my current append code, I did try CMSampleBuffer first on realtime, which im not sure why didnt work. I suspect that the realtime feature only applies to the AV components of iOS devices and not other connected devices. Then I tried this which should probably work but is not. I tried both 30 and 60fps, it's supposed to be 30 though. Am I misusing CMTime? Because I was attempting to just not use CMTime and that did not work as I mentioned.

```
        if self.videoDecoder.isRecording,
            let videoPixelBuffer = self.videoDecoder.videoWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor,
            videoPixelBuffer.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            print(videoPixelBuffer.append(frame, withPresentationTime: CMTimeMake(value: self.videoDecoder.videoFrameCounter, timescale: 30)))
            self.videoDecoder.videoFrameCounter += 1
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us you `append` code?

Comment: @Aznix I added it to the bottom of the question as an edit

Comment: 1) Are you sure that you getting `CMSampleBuffer`s? 2) Is `append` function returns `true`?

Comment: that edit is for CVPivelBuffer, it does return true like that and has made 60+mb corrupt .mp4 files

Comment: Hmm, try to add some outputSettings, etc. fileType to `AVAssetWriterInput`. If fileType not setted writer define it as .mov file sampleBuffer. Maybe your external device do not send .mov file sampleBuffer

Comment: When I add the output settings I get PHPhotosErrorDomain error 3302, for outputSettings = {
    AVVideoCodecKey = avc1;
    AVVideoHeightKey = 720;
    AVVideoWidthKey = 1280;
} for avc1 is h264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my final code solution - the final issue I had was that CMTime is used very strangely by some example projects i found on Github/Google. Also I was unable to figure out a way to send my mp4 files to the photo library - they would always be grey videos with the correct size/length. So I had to access them from the app files directory on the device.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AssetsLibrary

final class VideoRecorder: NSObject {

var isRecording: Bool = false
private var frameDuration: CMTime = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
private var nextPTS: CMTime = .zero
private var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?
private var assetWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
private var path = ""
private var outputURL: URL?

private func createFilePath() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    guard let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first as NSURL? else {
        print("Error: documentDir Error")
        return
    }
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
    guard let videoOutputURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyRecording_\(month)-\(day)_\(hour)-\(minute)-\(second).mp4") else {
        print("Error: Cannot create Video Output file path URL")
        return
    }
    self.outputURL = videoOutputURL
    self.path = videoOutputURL.path
    print(self.path)
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
            return
        }
    }
}

public func startStop() {
    if self.isRecording {
        self.stopRecording() { successfulCompletion in
            print("Stopped Recording: \(successfulCompletion)")
        }
    } else {
        self.startRecording()
    }
}

private func startRecording() {
    guard !self.isRecording else {
        print("Warning: Cannot start recording because \(Self.self) is already recording")
        return
    }
    self.createFilePath()
    print("Started Recording")
    self.isRecording = true
}

public func appendFrame(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
    // set up the AVAssetWriter using the format description from the first sample buffer captured
    if self.assetWriter == nil {
        let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)
        guard self.setupAssetWriter(format: formatDescription) else {
            print("Error: Failed to set up asset writer")
            self.assetWriter = nil
            return
        }
    }
    guard self.assetWriter != nil else {
        print("Error: Attempting to append frame when AVAssetWriter is nil")
        return
    }
    // re-time the sample buffer - in this sample frameDuration is set to 30 fps
    var timingInfo = CMSampleTimingInfo.invalid // a way to get an instance without providing 3 CMTime objects
    timingInfo.duration = self.frameDuration
    timingInfo.presentationTimeStamp = self.nextPTS
    var sbufWithNewTiming: CMSampleBuffer? = nil
    guard CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer,
                                                sampleTimingEntryCount: 1, // numSampleTimingEntries
                                                sampleTimingArray: &timingInfo,
                                                sampleBufferOut: &sbufWithNewTiming) == 0 else {
        print("Error: Failed to set up CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming")
        return
    }
    
    // append the sample buffer if we can and increment presentation time
    guard let writeInput = self.assetWriterInput, writeInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData else {
        print("Error: AVAssetWriterInput not ready for more media")
        return
    }
    guard let sbufWithNewTiming = sbufWithNewTiming else {
        print("Error: sbufWithNewTiming is nil")
        return
    }
    
    if writeInput.append(sbufWithNewTiming) {
        self.nextPTS = CMTimeAdd(self.frameDuration, self.nextPTS)
    } else if let error = self.assetWriter?.error {
        logError(error)
        print("Error: Failed to append sample buffer: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Error: Something went horribly wrong with appending sample buffer")
    }
    // release the copy of the sample buffer we made
}

private func setupAssetWriter(format formatDescription: CMFormatDescription?) -> Bool {
    // allocate the writer object with our output file URL
    let videoWriter: AVAssetWriter
    do {
        videoWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: self.path), fileType: AVFileType.mp4)
    } catch {
        logError(error)
        return false
    }
    guard formatDescription != nil else {
        print("Error: No Format For Video to create AVAssetWriter")
        return false
    }
    // initialize a new input for video to receive sample buffers for writing
    // passing nil for outputSettings instructs the input to pass through appended samples, doing no processing before they are written
    let videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: nil, sourceFormatHint: formatDescription)
    videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    guard videoWriter.canAdd(videoInput) else {
        print("Error: Cannot add Video Input to AVAssetWriter")
        return false
    }
    videoWriter.add(videoInput)
    
    // initiates a sample-writing at time 0
    self.nextPTS = CMTime.zero
    videoWriter.startWriting()
    videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime.zero)
    self.assetWriter = videoWriter
    self.assetWriterInput = videoInput
    return true
}

private func stopRecording(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    guard self.isRecording else {
        print("Warning: Cannot stop recording because \(Self.self) is not recording")
        completion(false)
        return
    }
    self.isRecording = false
    guard assetWriter != nil else {
        print("Error: AssetWriter is nil")
        completion(false)
        return
    }
    assetWriterInput?.markAsFinished()
    assetWriter?.finishWriting() {
        self.assetWriter = nil
        self.assetWriterInput = nil
        self.path = ""
        self.outputURL = nil
        completion(true)
    }
}
}
```